# Hibernate error while trying to start WAS 6.1

Tags: hibernate, websphere

When I try to start the WAS 6.1, I get the error:

```
[07/07/11 14:15:40:518 EDT] 0000001d SessionFactor W org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance Could not bind factory to JNDI
                                 javax.naming.NoPermissionException: NO_PERMISSION exception caught [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION: Not authorized to perform bind_new_corba_context operation.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doCreateSubcontext(CNContextImpl.java:2992)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.createSubcontext(CNContextImpl.java:1003)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.createSubcontext(WsnInitCtx.java:390)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:435)
    at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.bind(NamingHelper.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance(SessionFactoryObjectFactory.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1176)
```

What permission is this referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiberante is trying to bind something to the name space (the JNDI name space that is hosted by WAS).

I am not sure about the policy (security config) of your WAS environment. It can be configured to allow only certiain users to change things in the name server.

Refer to the following for some info in this space.

I have linked you to V7 but the info is the same for 6.1 too. Replace v7r0 in the link below to v6r1 to find the equivalent info in V6.1

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_naming.html

HTH

Manglu